# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to 0+}\int_{x}^{2x}\frac{\sin^mt}{t^n}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

> Evaluate the limit  $$\lim_{x \to 0+}\int_{x}^{2x}\frac{\sin^mt}{t^n}dt$$ where m ,n are natural numbers. Take cases when $m\ge n$,,when $n-m=1$,when $n-m>1$

I started out by multipying numerator and denominator by x and then used L-hospitals rule, but it became very ugly. I was left without options as problems of this type usually could be solved by this method.So here are somethings i tried to use :

when $m=n$

$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin^mt}{t^n}=1$$

when $m>n$
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin^mt}{t^n}=0$$
when $m<n$:

$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin^mt}{t^n}$ is not defined

I am looking for a solution that uses elementary methods. Somethings i already know are leibnitz rule,squeeze play theorem

Comment: Hint: for small $x$, the integrand is asymptotic to $t^{m-n}$, so the integral is asymptotic to $\frac{2^{m-n+1}-1}{m-n+1}x^{m-n+1}$ for $m-n+1\ne0$, or $\ln2$ otherwise.

Comment: @J.G. i have not learnt about asymptodic, is there a way to find without that, say by squeeze theorem

Comment: If you fix $x>0$, there's a $c\in[0,\,1]$, with $\lim_{x\to0^+}c=1$, such that $ct\le\sin t\le t$ for all $t\in[x,\,2x]$. That will allow you to replace my asymptotic analyses with uses of the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, that I suppose can be fruitful.
By the mean value theorem, $\exists \xi\in(x,2x)$ such that
$$
\int_x^{2x}\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}dt=x \frac{(\sin \xi)^m}{\xi^n}
$$
moreover
$$
\frac{1}{2^nx^n}\leq\frac{1}{\xi^n}\leq\frac{1}{x^n}
$$
and for small $x,$ such that $0<x<\pi/2$
$$
(\sin x)^m\leq(\sin\xi)^m\leq[\sin(2x)]^m
$$
It suggests, by the squeeze theorem, that the result is $0$ for $m\geq n$ and $+\infty$ for $n-m>1$, but fails to give information for the most interesting case $n-m=1.$

**Edit**

Following the suggestion of @J.G. (see comment to the question)
$$
ct\leq \sin t\leq t, \qquad \forall t\in[x,2x]
$$
so that
$$
c^mt^{m-n}=\frac{(ct)^m}{t^n}\leq\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}\leq\frac{t^m}{t^n}=t^{m-n}
$$
The integral becomes immediate: if $m-n\neq-1$
$$
c^m\left.\frac{t^{m-n+1}}{m-n+1}\right|_x^{2x}=\int_x^{2x} c^mt^{m-n}dt\leq\int_x^{2x}\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}dt\leq\int_x^{2x} t^{m-n}dt=\left.\frac{t^{m-n+1}}{m-n+1}\right|_x^{2x}
$$
and finally
$$
c^m\frac{2^{m-n+1}-1}{m-n+1}x^{m-n+1}\leq\int_x^{2x}\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}dt\leq\frac{2^{m-n+1}-1}{m-n+1}x^{m-n+1}
$$
If $m-n>-1$ them $\lim_{x\to0} x^{m-n+1}=0$ and the integral is $0$.
If $m-n<-1$ them $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{m-n+1}=+\infty$ and the coefficient
$$
\frac{2^{m-n+1}-1}{m-n+1}
$$
is positive, and so the integrale is $+\infty.$
Finally, if $m-n=-1,$ then
$$
c^m\frac{1}{t}\leq\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}\leq\frac{1}{t}
$$
and
$$
c^m\ln 2=c^m\left.\ln t\right|_x^{2x}=\int_x^{2x}c^m\frac{1}{t}dt\leq\int_x^{2x}\frac{(\sin t)^m}{t^n}dt\leq\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}dt=\left.\ln t\right|_x^{2x}=\ln 2
$$
and given that $c\to1$ when $x\to0^+$, the integral evaluate to $\ln 2$.

Comment: indeed that is the most difficult  case , thank you for putting effort for the  other cases,

Comment: Suggestion by @J.G. works for that case and it's simpler in general

Comment: the point is i cant understand @J.G method,

Comment: If them have no interest in writing an answer, I can edit my answer and add some details

Comment: Yes that will help

Comment: thanks for the complete answer